# Detect if string contains a float?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

How can I detect if a string contains a float. For example: `'0.004'`

But without using `StrToFloat` because that function are slow but rather by iterating through chars.

```
function IsInteger(const S: String): Boolean;
var
  P: PChar;
begin
  P := PChar(S);
  Result := True;
  while not (P^ = #0) do
  begin
    case P^ of
      '0'..'9': Inc(P);
    else
      Result := False;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This will check if string is a positive integer but not a float..

Comment: How did you find out they are slow ? And what prevents you from doing what you want ?

Comment: @TLama Run them in a loop from 0 to 10000000 and you will see what i mean. Not to mention they throw an exception.

Comment: Well, IntToStr and StrToInt make no sense here since you ask about floats. Do anything 10 million times and expect to wait a little while.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Whoops.

Comment: After your edit adding code, you seem to be confusing `Integer` with `Float` - which one do you want?

Comment: @JerryDodge I am saying if it can be done in a similar fashion.

Comment: Your `IsInteger` function is flawed.

Comment: Code in the question is broken. Apparently -1 is not an integer.

Comment: Where are you stuck with converting the IsInteger function?

Answer (score 7):

I would use TryStrToFloat():

```
if TryStrToFloat(str, value, FormatSettings) then
  ....
```

If you are prepared to use the default system wide format settings then you can omit the final parameter:

```
if TryStrToFloat(str, value) then
  ....
```

Comment: Are you sure ? In Delphi 2009 it calls `TextToFloat`.

Comment: @TLama Yes I am sure. Trying converting a non float and it won't throw an exception.

Comment: @user Why do you say that? The fact that a function does not raise an exception does not prove that it calls a function that does, and catches it. What really happens is that StrToFloat calls TryStrToFloat (or a moral equivalent), and raises if TryStrToFloat returns False.

Comment: What of it. This is still how I would do it. If you would care to present performance requirements then let's see if we can do better than this. But saying "it's slow" is not really very illuminating. So, if you want to talk about performance, can you state clearly your requirements please.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan All I am saying is iterating through chars would be faster IMHO. Than TryStrtToFloat.

Comment: How fast do you need? What is your typical input? Optimising depends heavily on that info. Show us what profiling and timing you have done so far.

Comment: If the string was 1,000 characters long, it might start to get slow, but if a string is 1,000 characters long, I would automatically assume it's not a float value.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a RegEx here?   Something like:

```
([+-]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)
```

Comment: How about 1e1 for example?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this question is that saying "is too slow" doesn't tell much. What does the profiler tells to you? Do you have an informed idea about the input data? What about different notations, for example, `6.02e23`?

If your input data is mostly noise, then using regular expressions (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20229255/7841)) may improve things but only as a first filter. You could then add a second step to actually obtain your number, as explained by [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20229190/7841).